# Will an existing badge get upgraded if I earn more score?

Tags: discussion, badges

Let's say I post a question which gets to a score of 10 and is then awarded the *"Nice Question"* badge.

Then the same question goes on to receive a score of 25 — the previous 10 plus 15 more.
In this situation, how will badges be awarded? For the same question, do I have two badges, now, *"Nice Question"* (bronze) and *"Good Question"* (silver) or just *"Good Question"* as if it were upgraded from *"Nice Question"*?

Reference badges that Stack Overflow supports:

- Nice Question (bronze): Question score of 10 or more
- Good Question (silver): Question score of 25 or more
- Great Question (gold): Question score of 100 or more

Comment: [Badges? BADGES?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqomZQMZQCQ)

Comment: Currently, the score for the question is 28 and you are received _Nice Question_ (bronze) and _Good Question_ (silver) badges. ie., For the same question, you can be awarded two badges.

Answer (score 48):

Once a badge is awarded, it can't be reverted.
So you will receive all three badges if the question gets to a total score of 100.

Comment: I think that badges are recalculated (and can be removed) when multiple accounts are merged.

Comment: Non-tag badges can be revoked in a few exceptional circumstances. Tag badges (badges awarded for contributions in a single tag) can be revoked if you no longer meet the requirements for that badge (for example, if you got downvoted, had an answer deleted etc). [More info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/179041)